# How can I combine two functions?

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio, function, recursion

I'm working in my project on something that gets an array and finds the max and min numbers and i did it with two separate functions and i want to combine them to a one function.
How can I do that properly?

The first function finds the maximum number in the array and the second function finds the minimum and I'm trying to get it to a function called MinMaxArray for example.

THE CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100 

int maximum(int array[], int index, int len);
int minimum(int array[], int index, int len);


int main()
{
    int array[MAX_SIZE], N, max, min;
    int i;
    printf("Enter size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("Enter %d elements in array: ", N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    max = maximum(array, 0, N);
    min = minimum(array, 0, N);

    printf("Minimum element in array = %d\n", min);
    printf("Maximum element in array = %d\n", max);

    return 0;
}



int maximum(int array[], int index, int len)
{
    int max;
    if (index >= len - 2)
    {
        if (array[index] > array[index + 1])
            return array[index];
        else
            return array[index + 1];
    }
    max = maximum(array, index + 1, len);

    if (array[index] > max)
        return array[index];
    else
        return max;
}


int minimum(int array[], int index, int len)
{
    int min;

    if (index >= len - 2)
    {
        if (array[index] < array[index + 1])
            return array[index];
        else
            return array[index + 1];
    }

    min = minimum(array, index + 1, len);

    if (array[index] < min)
        return array[index];
    else
        return min;
}
```

Comment: For example make a new function `minmax(int array[], int index, int len, int mode)`. When `mode ` is 1 it returns the maximum, when it's 0 it return the minimum.

Comment: Your recursive searching for max and min can, for large arrays, cause a call stack overflow. Why recursive anyway? What is wrong with  a loop? That would also make it easier to merge the two functions.

Comment: I am forced to use recursive functions because this is the task the university lecturer gave us ..

Comment: @ShayFletcher Most university classes teaching recursion are harmful, sadly. There exists very few real-world cases where you can and should use recursion. It saddens me that almost every beginner class seems to address recursion, because beginners can't tell when it makes sense to use. Most often, avoid it like the plague.

Comment: @Shay Fletcher Where are you hurry? See my answer. It is actually the best answer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow its a good answer but i cant use #include <time.h>

Comment: @ShayFletcher It is just a demonstrative program.  I showed how the function can be written. You can use your function with your own arrays. You selected a bad answer as the best.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Define a struct like this to return:

```
typedef struct
{
    int min;
    int max;
}vector;
```

Function 1:

```
vector MinMax(int array[], int index, int len)
{
    vector temp;

    temp.min = minimum(array,index,len);     
    temp.max = maximum(array,index,len);  //using the two function written by you

    return temp;
}
```

Function 2 (or): (use debugger to know how function works exactly)

```
vector MinMax(int array[], int len)      //len is from 0
{
    static vector v;                     // static variable

    v.min = array[len];                  // assign value of array respect to len
    v.max = array[len];

    if( (len-1) >= 0 )                   // check (len-1) is <= 0 to call function again
    {
       MinMax(array,len-1);
    }

    if(v.min > array[len])               //compare and store
        v.min = array[len];

    if(v.max < array[len])               //compare and store
        v.max = array[len];

    return v;                            //return 
}
```

Thanks.(Sorry for bad English, I am not well in English)

Comment: Please provide reason to down vote it helps to correct the code

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer. Stack Overflow is not intended to be a free coding service. It is intended to provide a durable repository of questions and answers. Preferably, answers should give generally useful information, including explanations of coding techniques, not just specific code.

Comment: I did not vote down. But it seems to me the comments you added do not discuss the most important idea, the  use of the structure you added to return two values.

Answer (score 0):

Two options here. Output arguments or return a struct.

```
struct vector2d {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct vector2d minmax1(int array[], int index, int len)
{
    struct vector2d ret;
    int max, min;
    // Calculate max and min however you want
    ret.x = max;
    ret.y = min;
    return ret;
}

void minmax1(int array[], int index, int len, int *minval, int *maxval)
{
    int max, min;
    // Calculate max and min however you want
    *minval = min;
    *maxval = max;
}
```

Comment: Providing an index to the items instead of the values is a good idea, because then the caller knows that min is found at `arr[i]` and if they want to know the value too, they can just de-reference that item.

Comment: @lundin.  Good idea.  Also when  `len==0` (or array ==NULL) then the pointer can be `NULL` to indicate no minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Another viable option:

Forget about these functions and `qsort` your data instead. Then afterwards simply grab item number `0` and item number `n` - voilà, there's your min and max. As a bonus, further searching through the data can be carried out with "O(log n)" from now on, since it is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to declare only two parameters for the combined function of searching the minimum ans the maximum of an array.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Pair { size_t min; size_t max; }
minmax_element( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    struct Pair current = { .min = 0, .max = 0 };

    if ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        struct Pair prev = minmax_element( a + 1, n - 1 );

        if ( a[prev.min + 1] < a[current.min] ) current.min = prev.min + 1; 
        if ( a[current.max] < a[prev.max + 1] ) current.max = prev.max + 1; 
    }

    return current;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[N];

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = rand() % ( int )N;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    struct Pair minmax = minmax_element( a, N );

    printf( "The minimum element is %d at position %zu\n", 
            a[minmax.min], minmax.min );

    printf( "The maximum element is %d at position %zu\n", 
            a[minmax.max], minmax.max );

    return 0;
}
```

Here are several possible program outputs.

```
9 1 2 9 1 0 7 1 5 5 
The minimum element is 0 at position 5
The maximum element is 9 at position 0
```

or

```
9 4 2 9 3 9 9 5 7 0 
The minimum element is 0 at position 9
The maximum element is 9 at position 0
```

or

```
4 3 4 9 1 3 6 9 3 3 
The minimum element is 1 at position 4
The maximum element is 9 at position 3
```